# Not able to connect (using ftp and command line with) server via pem file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have instance id, public DNS IP address, .pem file. I tried to connect to an EC2 instance using FileZilla but each time it fails saying `could not authenticate (server: public key sent)`.

How can I connect using filezilla to EC2 instance?

I have tried putty too but it also gives an error and can't let me log in.

When tried using command line `ssh -i My.pem root@ec2-myipaddress.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` it also gives error Permission denied (public key).

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -i My.pem root@ec2-myipaddress.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`
Its give permission issue so first of all run below command

`sudo chmod 400 My.pem`

After that try to connect with ssh command

and for file transfer use winSCP Tool.

you can check here for more detail

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Thanks